# Pegar palavra no meio de um texto

Tags: php

Preciso pegar a palavra *tutorial.pdf* que esta no meio do link.

Essa palavra sempre ira mudar de acordo com o arquivo que for selecionado.

```
<a href="uploads/tutorial.pdf">tutorial.pdf</a>
```

Comment: O texto da descrição ou do `href`?

Comment: Não é mais simples pegar a 'descrição' do link com javascript?

Comment: O código do href retorna direto do banco, Sendo assim só quero exibir o nome do arquivo. Se ele for retirado de "uploads/tutorial.pdf" ou da descrição do href não tem problema.

Comment: Posta seu código php que insere esse html, assim fica mais fácil obter uma resposta já encaixada no que você precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar **regex** e passar para o `preg_match()` o padrão utilizado na formação da string

```
$input = '<a href="uploads/tutorial.pdf">tutorial.pdf</a>';

if (preg_match("/<a href=\"uploads\/(.*)\">/s",$input, $results)){
    print_r($results[1]);
}
```

Nesse exemplo, ele esta extraindo o conteúdo **tutorial.pdf** de de dentro da propriedade `href`

**UPDATE**

Como você disse o conteúdo do `href` esta vindo do banco, você pode usar **regex** para extrair o texto entre a `/` e o `.pdf`

```
$link = 'uploads/tutorial.pdf';

if (preg_match("/\/(.*)\.pdf/s",$link, $results)){
    print_r($results[1]);
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado! funcionou da maneira que eu precisava.

Comment: vale a penas dar uma estudada em regex, é muito versátil e pode ser utilizado em praticamente todas as linguagens

Answer (score 2):

## Utilize a função `split`

Essa função retorna um array de strings a partir de um delimitador, neste caso o nosso delimitador é `/`.

```
$link = "uploads/tutorial.pdf";

$fileName = split ("/", $link);

print "$fileName[0] <br />"; // retorno "uploads"
print "$fileName[1] <br />" ;// retorno "tutorial.pdf"
```

Comment: [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) é depreciada e foi removida do php7, nesse caso troque por [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: fiz a alteração utilizando o explode, porem esta me retornando no finame[1] omprovante.pdf">comprovante.pdf

Comment: Alterei o delimitador para ">" é agora esta trazendo o que eu preciso.

Comment: percebi que esta pegando comprovante.pdf </a , o que eu posso fazer para ir até o .pdf?

Comment: @Diogo se o seu propósito é remover o </a, utilize a função str_replace $text = str_replace('</a','',$text)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php):

```
$html = '<a href="uploads/tutorial1.pdf">tutorial1.pdf</a>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);

echo $xml;         // tutorial1.pdf  
echo $xml['href']; // uploads/tutorial1.pdf
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/TjG8Sb)</kbd>

Uma outra alternativa é a classe [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php), você pode usar a função [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) para selecionar todos os elementos com a tag `a` e obter seus valores:

```
$html = '<a href="uploads/tutorial1.pdf">tutorial1.pdf</a>
         <a href="uploads/tutorial2.pdf">tutorial1.pdf</a>
         <a href="uploads/tutorial3.pdf">tutorial1.pdf</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->nodeValue . ": " . $tag->getAttribute('href') . "\n";
}

// tutorial1.pdf: uploads/tutorial1.pdf
// tutorial1.pdf: uploads/tutorial2.pdf
// tutorial1.pdf: uploads/tutorial3.pdf
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/5wldHf)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar também a combinação de `split()` com `end()`:

```
$link       = "uploads/tutorial.pdf";
$file       = split ("/", $link);
$fileName   = end($file);

echo $fileName;
```

> tutorial.pdf

Comment: $link       = "<a href="uploads/tutorial.pdf">tutorial.pdf</a>";                            neste caso preciso que seja exatamente o código do href, pois ele ja tras o código do banco

Comment: Como assim o código ?

Comment: ele não me tras apenas o caminho e sim o código html do link ja montado

Comment: Haaaaa, então já responderam. Tem que usar expressão regular.